# currentDate in correspondence rule Pega

Tags: function, date, pega

Currently working in Pega8.6.1, we want to put in an email(correspondence rule)/document a date field that shows a date plus 10 business days. The date should be 10 business days from the creation date of the email.
Have tried <%= pega_rules_datetime.pyCurrentDate.addDays("", 10, true, "") %> but am afraid I'm putting it wrong into the correspondence rule. In the generated email this formula is just shown as is.
Am fairly new with Pega so bear with me. Working now for about 2 months with Pega and afraid trying to reinvent the wheel.

Is what we are trying to establish even possible in Pega?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the +10 days value in a separate `property` on `Primary page` of the email.

For example if `pyWorkPage` is your `Primary page` then you can have a separate `property` for example `EmailPlusTen` on `pyWorkPage`.

Then you can write something like below in a `Data Transform` or in an `Activity` rule before calling you email logic.

`.EmailPlusTen = @(Pega-RULES:BusinessCalendar).addDays(@DateTime.CurrentDate("yyyyMMdd",""),10,true,"")`

Then you can directly include property `EmailPlusTen` in your `Correspondence` rule by using this tag `<<.EmailPlusTen>>`

If you are using an activity to send the email then you can create a Parameter value and set it in the Activity before email logic.

for e.g.

`Param.EmailPlusTen = @(Pega-RULES:BusinessCalendar).addDays(@DateTime.CurrentDate("yyyyMMdd",""),10,true,"")`

And then include it in Email Correspondence `<<Param.EmailPlusTen>>`

Comment: Thanks, will try that out

Comment: Thanks that did indeed do the job we needed.